# Spring Data JDBC - immutable owner of OneToMany relation

Tags: spring, spring-data-jdbc

I'm trying out Spring Data JDBC, and I think that immutable entities are the key feature here.

I want to model a one-to-many relationship between Team and Player and have these entities immutable. What I have working right now is:

```
@Getter
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
public class Team {
  @Id
  @Wither
  private Integer id;

  private String name;
  private List<Player> players;
}
```

```
@Value
public class Player {
  @Id
  @Wither
  Integer id;
  String name;
  public static Player of(String name) {
    return new Player(null, name);
  }
}
```

I managed to get a OneToMany relationship working properly for mutable classes. I managed to make it work for immutable Player. However, I can't get Team mapping to work without `@NoArgsConstructor`, or with `@Value` instead of what I have right now. I get the weird message as if Spring Data JDBC started seeing different mapping when this constructor is missing:

`Caused by: org.h2.jdbc.JdbcSQLSyntaxErrorException: Column "players_id" not found [42122-199]`

If anybody tries to recreate that scenario, here's my h2 schema:

```
create table team (id serial primary key, name varchar);
create table player (id serial primary key, name varchar, team int references team(id), team_key int);
```

And my Spock test:

```
@SpringBootTest
class TeamRepositoryTest extends Specification {
    @Autowired
    TeamRepository teamRepository

    def "Context loads"() {
        given:
        def rick = Player.of("Rick")
        def morty = Player.of("Morty")
        def team = new Team(null, "Rick and Morty", Arrays.asList(rick, morty))

        when:
        def savedTeam = teamRepository.save(team)

        then:
        def savedTeamOpt = teamRepository.findById(savedTeam.id)
        Team retrievedTeam = savedTeamOpt.get()
        retrievedTeam.id == savedTeam.id
        retrievedTeam.name == "Rick and Morty"
        retrievedTeam.players.size() == 2
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You hit a bug in Spring Data JDBC: https://jira.spring.io/browse/DATAJDBC-127

Currently entities or collections of entities don't work as constructor arguments. 
Create a constructor without these arguments and add setters or if you want to stay immutable *withers* for them.

Comment: Thank you very much! That's what I was suspecting. The risk of trying to be an early adopter :)

Comment: I actually can't reproduce the issue anymore with 1.1.M4 could you try to reproduce the issue with that version?

Comment: I think I used 1.0.8, I'll try your version when I'm home in a few hours

Comment: Confirmed - in 1.1.0.M4 the bug doesn't exist. However, I expected to be forced to use `@Wither` on players field, and it looks like it's not necessary - probably the AllArgsConstructor is used there (I have `@Value` annotation on Team).
Thank you, Jens!